# getting an x and y coordinate from a specific object in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, collision-detection

I am working on creating a game that has to do with objects(circles) falling from the top of the canvas. I have these circles randomly generating at x coordinates and then falling at a constant rate. I am trying to write a collision algorithm but cannot seem to access the x coordinates or width/height of the circles that are falling.

This is how I created the circles and put them in an array. var projectiles = [] was declared at the top of my code already

```
function spawnEnemies()
{
    var g1 = new createjs.Graphics();
    g1.beginStroke('white').beginFill('red').drawCircle(Math.floor(Math.random() * 650) + 50, 50, 20);
    var e = new createjs.Shape(g1);
    projectiles.push(e);
    stage.addChild(e);
}
```

This is my collision algorithm where I am trying to access the x and y coordinates of the circles and also retrieve their width and height. I used console.log to check and see what values are being returned. For p.x the value 0 is returned every time and p.width returns NaN. I am confused why p.x and p.width are not working.

```
function checkCollision()
{

for (i = 0; i < projectiles.length; i++) {
    var p = projectiles[i];
    if((p.x + width) < ship.x)
    {
        hit = false;
    }
    else if(p.x > (ship.x + ship.image.width))
    {
        hit = false;
    }
    else if(p.y > (ship.y + ship.image.height))
    {
        hit = false;
    }
    else if((p.y + p.height) < ship.y)
    {
        hit = false;
    }
    else
    {
        hit = true;
        console.log(p.x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` and `y` properties of a `Shape` can be used to translate it. In your code, you instead leave them as the default (0) and draw the circle at a specific location in the Shape's canvas.

If you want the `x` to reflect the location of the circle, consider changing `spawnEnemies` to always draw the circle at the Shape's origin, then setting its `x` to the desired location.

```
g1.(...).drawCircle(0, 50, 20);
var e = new createjs.Shape(g1);
e.x = Math.(...);
```

Comment: Could you provide a basic code example. I guess I don't fully understand what you mean